# How to retrieve the string after whitespace in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I want to append string `TimeClust` to a space, followed by the last string (digit) of the pandas series.

```
time_cluster = "TimeClust" + " ".join(treatment_info.loc["Time Cluster"].to_string().split())
```

Series:

```
treatment_info.loc["Time Cluster"]

0
12    Cluster 2
48    Cluster 3
4     Cluster 1
8     Cluster 4
0     Cluster 1

Name: Time Cluster, dtype: object
```

Expected output:

```
    0
    12    TimeClust_2
    48    TimeClust_3
    4     TimeClust_1
    8     TimeClust_4
    0     TimeClust_1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, You can use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

```
df['Time Cluster'] = df['Time Cluster'].str.replace('Cluster ', 'TimeClust_')
print(df)
```

---

```
    0 Time Cluster
0  12  TimeClust_2
1  48  TimeClust_3
2   4  TimeClust_1
3   8  TimeClust_4
4   0  TimeClust_1
```

Answer (score 0):

In more complex cases, you can use regex lookbehind assertion `(?<=\s)\w+`:

```
s = pd.Series(['foo 1', 'bar 22'])
s.str.extract(r'(?<=\s)(\w+)')
```

Output:

```
    0
0   1
1  22
```